# Connected App authentication failure with newly refreshed sandbox

Tags: sandbox, user, connected-apps, authentication

I have a connected app that uses the standard Username & Password+security token to auth. I have tested connecting to the app from a production org, sandbox and scratch org. They all work. This includes using login.salesforce.com, test.salesforce.com and <instance_id>.salesforce.com.

I'm running into bizarre behavior when I refresh my sandbox though. Once refreshed, I can not auth to my app using test.salesforce.com. I have to use the instance id. It shoots back the standard error message:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "authentication failure"
}
```

I have tried other sandboxes under the same org and they all work using the test prefix (with the same user).

Further more, it looks like when I wait a long period of time (days), the test prefix begins working again.

Is there anything disclosed by Salesforce that explains this behavior? I am stumped but it is impacting our org greatly whenever a sandbox refresh happens

Comment: have you tried mydomain?

Comment: I haven't but I have tried (successfully) with instanceid.saleforce.com. The issue is this code needs to be pushed to multiple sandboxes so the endpoint url (in a named credential) needs to be agnostic to any domain or instance.

Comment: could you use `Url.getOrgDomainUrl()` ?  this will generate the right url that takes into account mydomain plus the sandbox; e.g. it returns `https://mydomain--sandboxName.my.salesforce.com`

Comment: I recommended to check your user permissions. If you refresh sandbox, maybe your user lost a permission set which allows to authorise to this org.